# AngularStrap date-template

Tags: angularjs

## Problema

Estou implementando o StrapAngular em minha aplicação, porém não consigo utilizar o contentTamplate para inserir um formulário em meu modal aside.

tentei da seguinte forma

#### mainCtrl

```
$scope.aside = {
            "title": "Novo agendamento",
            "contentTemplate":  'views/agenda/form-novo-agendamento.tpl.html'
        };
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" bs-aside="aside">
    Novo agendamento
</button>
```

O titulo é preenchido corretamente mas o conteúdo não vem, ocorre o mesmo com a inserção do template direto do data-template:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-template="views/agenda/form-novo-agendamento.tpl.html" data-placement="left" data-animation="am-slide-left" bs-aside="aside" data-container="body">Novo agendamento
</button>
```

### Obrigado desde já!

Comment: por curiosidade, por que escolheu angularstrap em vez de angularui ? rs :)

Comment: Porque ele se adapta certinho ao visual que quero para aplicação, como por exemplo o Aside, os dropdown...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solução

Mudando um pouco o foco disso estava fazendo outra parte aqui do sistema e acabo me dando uma **'luz'** sobre oque poderia ser feito, e a solução foi simples.

Passando o data-content-template diretamente no meu documento HTML tive o retorno do meu template, ficando assim meu codigo:

```
<button type="button" data-content-template="views/agenda/novo-agendamento.tpl.html" data-template="views/agenda/modal.tpl.html" bs-aside="novoAgendamentoModal">Novo agendamento</button>
```

Porém diretamente no JS não consegui passar o meu tpl, caso alguém tenha um modo para isso pode ficar a vontade para inserir a solução.